# ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.PersistedModelLocalServiceRegistry cannot be found by Service.service

Tags: osgi-bundle, liferay-7

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.PersistedModelLocalServiceRegistry cannot be found by Service.service_1.0.0
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:450) ~[org.eclipse.osgi.jar:?]